# How would I show that the inverse function of my 'ratio' function is continuous?

Tags: general-topology

"Let $f,g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions such that $f(x) > g(x) \;  \forall \;  x \in \mathbb{R}$. Define subspaces $X,Y $ of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ as:

$X := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} : g(x) \leq y \leq f(x)\}$

$Y := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} : 0 \leq y \leq 1\}$

Show $X \cong Y$."

I've constructed a function $h: X \rightarrow Y$ given by

$h(x,y) = (x, \alpha)$ where $\alpha = \frac{y - g(x)}{f(x) - g(x)}$

and I've shown it to be a bijection, but I am struggling to get going with showing that its inverse is continuous. Namely, how would I find this inverse function? Is my construction not an optimal choice (in terms of how much work is required to solve this)? Moreover, how can I show that this inverse is continuous? Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note you can, given $f(x)>g(x)$ and the definitions of $X,Y,$ drop absolute value bars and write $\alpha=\frac{y-g(x)}{f(x)-g(x)}.$

Comment: Thank you, I see that now

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> If we write $(u, v) = h(x, y)$, the task is to express $(x, y)$ as a (continuous) function of $(u, v)$. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse is$$(x,y)\mapsto\bigl(x,y\bigl(f(x)-g(x)\bigr)+g(x)\bigr),$$which is clearly continuous.